# Efficient NEON intrinsics for C++/SSE code

Tags: c++, arm, sse, neon, intrinsics

How to efficiently convert the following code snippet into NEON intrinsics?

**C++**

```
int diff_scale, c0, c1;
cost = (short)(cost + std::min(c0, c1) >> diff_scale));
```

**SSE**

```
__m128i ds = _mm_cvtsi32_si128(diff_scale);
__m128i c0 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)(cost));
__m128i c1 = _mm_load_si128((__m128i*)(cost + 8));
__m128i z = _mm_setzero_si128();    
_mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(cost), _mm_adds_epi16(c0, _mm_srl_epi16(_mm_unpacklo_epi8(diff, z), ds)));
_mm_store_si128((__m128i*)(cost + 8), _mm_adds_epi16(c1, _mm_srl_epi16(_mm_unpackhi_epi8(diff, z), ds)));
```

Comment: Benchmark the plain C++ code first - you may well find it's fast enough that you don't need a SIMD (Neon) version.

Comment: The reason I wrote this in SSE in the first place was because the C++ was slow (much slower than the SIMD version). Now, I'm merely trying to extend this to ARM devices. In other words, yes, the C++ version is slow and I do need the SIMD version. :)

Comment: If you're assuming that Neon will make as big a difference as SSE then you may be slightly disappointed.

Comment: Can you explain why? Converting this linear code to SIMD gave a huge speedup on Intel architecture - so why not on ARM? Please note that this line of code, albeit looking simple, is being called several thousand times.

Comment: ARM is a much more bare bones architecture - you'll get some speed up with Neon but it probably won't be as dramatic as the improvement with SSE.

Comment: That is, in fact, what I observe as well. While the NEON version runs faster than C++, it isn't as dramatic as the SSE. I just assumed my NEON port was bad. Do you have any other suggestions to improve performance for ARM devices?

Comment: There is also a secondary problem in that the ARM gcc back-end does not generate very good Neon code from intrinsics - you can typically beat it by a factor of 2 if you resort to hand-coded assembler, but obviously that's a pain to have to deal with. SSE/AVX code gen in the x86 versions of gcc and clang OTOH is very good.

Comment: The C and SSE code seem to do very different arithmetic with the same variable names. Is that right?

Comment: @PaulR While GCC's NEON code gen still isn't perfect, it has massively improved. It is several years since there was a factor of two difference between intrinsics and assembler.

Comment: @CharlesBaylis: thanks - I haven't looked at his for 2-3 years - it's good to hear that things have improved - what version of gcc (minimum) would you recommend ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SSE looks like it should be something like this:

```
int8x16_t ds = vdupq_n_s8(-diff_scale);
int16x8_t c0 = vld1q_s16(cost);
int16x8_t c1 = vld1q_s16(cost + 8);
uint8x16_t diff_ds = vshlq_u8(diff, ds);
#if defined(MAY_SATURATE)
vst1q_s16(cost,     vqaddq_s16(c0, vreinterpretq_s16_u16(vmovl_u8(vget_low_u8(diff_ds)))));
vst1q_s16(cost + 8, vqaddq_s16(c1, vreinterpretq_s16_u16(vmovl_u8(vget_high_s8(diff_ds)))));
#else
vst1q_s16(cost,     vreinterpretq_s16_u16(vaddw_u16(vreinterpretq_u16_s16(c0), vget_low_u8(diff_ds))));
vst1q_s16(cost + 8, vreinterpretq_s16_u16(vaddw_u16(vreinterpretq_u16_s16(c1), vget_high_s8(diff_ds))));
#endif
```

The C++ needs some kind of extrapolation to vectors... maybe something like this?:

```
int diff_scale, c0[8], c1[8];
int32x4_t ds = vdupq_n_s32(-diff_scale);
int32x4_t c0lo = vld1q_s32(c0);
int32x4_t c0hi = vld1q_s32(c0 + 4);
int32x4_t c1lo = vld1q_s32(c1);
int32x4_t c1hi = vld1q_s32(c1 + 4);
int16x8_t c = vld1q_s16(cost);
c0lo = vshlq_s32(vaddw_s32(vminq_s32(c0lo, c1lo), vget_low_s16(c), ds);
c0hi = vshlq_s32(vaddw_s32(vminq_s32(c0hi, c1hi), vget_high_s16(c), ds);
vst1q_s16(cost, vcombine_s16(vmovn_s16(c0lo), vmovn_s16(c0hi)));
```

If `diff_scale` were a constant, then this instead:

```
const int diff_scale = 1;
int c0[8], c1[8];
int32x4_t c0lo = vld1q_s32(c0);
int32x4_t c0hi = vld1q_s32(c0 + 4);
int32x4_t c1lo = vld1q_s32(c1);
int32x4_t c1hi = vld1q_s32(c1 + 4);
int16x8_t c = vld1q_s16(cost);
c = vcombine_s16(vshrn_n_s32(vaddw_s32(vminq_s32(c0lo, c1lo), vget_low_s16(c), diff_scale),
                 vshrn_n_s32(vaddw_s32(vminq_s32(c0hi, c1hi), vget_high_s16(c), diff_scale));
vst1q_s16(cost, c);
```

Although these all look like they could probably be made much simpler with more context.